# use ajax to get controller action render in same page

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

this is my code of the view

I have a dropdown with option having the value of /ControllerName/ActionName.

when i click the dropdown value it redirects me into the another  page with the selected ControllerName and ActionName. I want to render the view in this same very page using ajax. the view should be rendered inside the empty div tag below. can someone help me

```
@model Demo.Models.student

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

<h2>Hello student</h2>

<select id="foo">
    <option value="">Pick an Action</option>
  <option value="/home/index">Home</option>
    <option value="/home/profile">Profile</option>
</select>

<div id="main">


</div>


<script>
    document.getElementById("foo").onchange = function () {
        if (this.selectedIndex !== 0) {
            window.location.href = this.value;
        }
    };
</script>
```

Comment: Use `$('#main').load(yourUrl);` - [refer documentation](https://api.jquery.com/load/)

Comment: Then you have not added `jquery{version}.js`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>‌
<script type="text/javascript">
     $('#foo').change(function(){
          if($(this).val()!=""&&$(this).val!=null){
               $.ajax({
                   url:$('#foo').val(),
                   data:'',
                   type:'post',
                   success:function(data){
                       $('#main').html(data);
                   }
                })
           }
     });
</script>
```

This will help you to load pages in `main` `div`.

Comment: Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined

Comment: Add this before your script tag `<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>`. I have updated my answer. @AnujTamrakar

Comment: If no data is being passed to the controller method, then its a GET, not a POST. And `$('#main').load($('#foo').val());` is a bit simpler

Comment: wht if i have to invoke a post method by passing a model to the controller